# Quarkus REST service Exception handling

Tags: java, quarkus

I am using quarkus version `1.10.5.Final` and need to know how can I handle unknown endpoints. When I try to hit an endpoint on not implemented yet ,it just sends an `404 Not Found` rather than an exception which I would like to implement. I was unable to find a implementation of the same. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends a bit on the stack you're using. If you're using RESTEasy, you can define an `ExceptionMapper` to catch that:

```java
@Provider
public class NotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException exception) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: ++ https://www.knowledgefactory.net/2021/10/custom-exception-handling-in-quarkus.html - complete example